# How to annotate table bullets in Chicago Style?

Tags: writing-style

I have a table with a summary of information on various products with their pros and cons. I'm using Chicago style annotation with numbered superscript indicating which reference it pertains to. Do I need to put a number next to each bullet with information about the product or can I just put superscripts on the table's label text?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about English Language & Usage.  It's about advice for a particular style guide.

Answer (score 1):

If a footnote or endnote reference pertains to every item in the column, you can put the  superscript numbered after the column heading.  If it applies only to some of the bulleted items, each item that it applies to should be tagged with the footnote's number, superscripted.